# Can't get a TextArea on type TextArea in ZF2 view

Tags: css, zend-framework2, zend-form

This is my form code

```
  $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'abc',
         'type' => 'TextArea',
         'options' => array(
         'label' => _('Enter description'),
     ),
     'attributes' => array(
            'rows' => '1',
            'cols' =>'75',
        )

     ));
```

This is my view code

```
<?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('abc'))."<br>"; ?> 
<?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('abc'))."<br>"; ?>
```

The problem here is that I don't get a TextArea and instead get a normal textbox. It was working when I used the code

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('abc'))."<br>"; ?>
```

When I try to print label and input separately, It is not using its type and attributes. How can I correct this for my case.

Answer (score 2):

use in your view the zend view helper `formText` to print a textarea

```
echo $this->formText($form->get('abc'))
```

in your form class use as `type` => `Zend\Form\Element\Text`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html